# ¿How to get the bottomLeft and the topRight bounds of an sprite in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

First, i will explain myself...
I was trying to make an script for the camera to follow the player and keep itself inside the Map.
After a litle research i found out that you can use a property of tileMap called tileMap.localBounds.min to find the bottomLeft corner and tileMap.localBounds.max to find the topRight corner of a tilemap.
The problem with that is that my map is not a tileMap, it`s a sprite.
So i try the following...

```
public Transform target;
public GameObject theMap;
private Vector3 bottomLeftLimit;
private Vector3 topRightLimit;

// These values are for the camera

private float halfHeight;
private float halfWidth;
void start()
{
    target = PlayerController.instance.transform;

    halfHeight = Camera.main.orthographicSize;
    halfWidth = halfHeight * Camera.main.aspect;

    // We assign the corners of our map
    // Maybe we`ll have to change the image for a tileMap to use: tileMap.localBounds 
    bottomLeftLimit = theMap.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.min + new Vector3(halfWidth, halfHeight, 0f);
    topRightLimit = theMap.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.max  + new Vector3(-halfWidth, -halfHeight, 0f);

    // We send the bound limits to the PlayerController script to keep the player inside the map
    PlayerController.instance.SetBounds(theMap.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.min, theMap.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite.bounds.max);
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = new Vector3(target.position.x, target.position.y, transform.position.z);

    // Keep the camera inside the bounds
    transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, bottomLeftLimit.x, topRightLimit.x), Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.y, bottomLeftLimit.y, topRightLimit.y), transform.position.z);
}
```

But it seems that the value of sprite.bounds.max and sprite.bounds.min are always 0 (the center), so it doesn`t work to set the bounds for the camera.

Anyone can help? I would aprecciate it a lot...

Comment: I would use [`GetWorldCorners`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RectTransform.GetWorldCorners.html). The `Image` component should have a reference to its `RectTransform`. You now have the world position of each of the corners of your sprite.

Comment: @TEEBQNE SpriteRenderer` is no `Image` and doesn't necessarily have a `RectTransform` though

Comment: Have you tried simply using the [`SpriteRenderer.bounds`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Renderer-bounds.html) directly?

Comment: @derHugo Very true had completely overlooked the `SpriteRenderer` component.

Answer (score 0):

**SpriteBoundsFinder.cs**

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class SpriteBoundsFinder : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Image image;

    private void Update()
    {
        var rectTransform = image.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        var sizeDelta = rectTransform.sizeDelta;
        var position = image.transform.position;
        var bottomLeft = position - new Vector3(sizeDelta.x / 2, sizeDelta.y / 2);
        var topRight = position + new Vector3(sizeDelta.x / 2, sizeDelta.y / 2);
        Debug.Log($"bottomLeft: {bottomLeft}, topRight: {topRight}");
    }
}
```

You can use this to find the bottom left and top right corner of a sprite in world space. Assuming you're using an overlay canvas. If not, let me know.

The reason this works is because a sprite will always be stretched to have the same width and height as the RectTransform of its Image component's GameObject.

Comment: i`ll try to implement the class you are suggesting, i`ll let you know if this works for me, thanks c:

Comment: Also, i would aprecciate if someone let me know whats wrong with my question because i received a -1 and i really don`t know why. It`s my first question, so if i can make it better please let me know